# Foreach giving wrong results when checking in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I have the library which checks for changing `DOM` elements and I have a big map array that contains almost all countries and capitals. 
When a new message in virtual chat appears, I check whether it contains key words and needed `country/capital` and gets the result in my text input. However, sometimes it gives me the wrong result. Capital of Belarus and some more countries give me `Washington.D.C`, when other ones work just fine and I cant seem to find why.

```
//Capitals Hunter
var CountryCapitalList = new Map();
CountryCapitalList.set("Afghanistan","Kabul");
CountryCapitalList.set("Albania","Tirana");
CountryCapitalList.set("Algeria","Algiers");
CountryCapitalList.set("Andorra","Andorra la Vella");
CountryCapitalList.set("Angola","Luanda");
CountryCapitalList.set("Antigua and Barbuda","Saint John's");
CountryCapitalList.set("Argentina","Buenos Aires");
CountryCapitalList.set("Armenia","Yerevan");
CountryCapitalList.set("Australia","Canberra");
CountryCapitalList.set("Austria","Vienna");
CountryCapitalList.set("Azerbaijan","Baku");
CountryCapitalList.set("Bahamas","Nassau");
CountryCapitalList.set("Bahrain","Manama");
CountryCapitalList.set("Bangladesh","Dhaka");
CountryCapitalList.set("Barbados","Bridgetown");
CountryCapitalList.set("Belarus","Minsk");
CountryCapitalList.set("Belgium","Brussels");
CountryCapitalList.set("Belize","Belmopan");
CountryCapitalList.set("Benin","Porto-Novo");
CountryCapitalList.set("Bhutan","Thimphu");
CountryCapitalList.set("Bolivia","  Sucre");
CountryCapitalList.set("Bosnia and Herzegovina","Sarajevo");
CountryCapitalList.set("Botswana","Gaborone");
CountryCapitalList.set("Brazil","Brasilia");
CountryCapitalList.set("Brunei","Bandar Seri Begawan");
CountryCapitalList.set("Bulgaria","Sofia");
CountryCapitalList.set("Burkina Faso","Ouagadougou");
CountryCapitalList.set("Burundi","Bujumbura");
CountryCapitalList.set("Cabo Verde","Praia");
CountryCapitalList.set("Cambodia","Phnom Penh");
CountryCapitalList.set("Cameroon","Yaounde");
CountryCapitalList.set("Canada","Ottawa");
CountryCapitalList.set("Central African Republic","Bangui");
CountryCapitalList.set("Chad","N'Djamena");
CountryCapitalList.set("Chile","Santiago");
CountryCapitalList.set("China","Beijing");
CountryCapitalList.set("Colombia","Bogotá");
CountryCapitalList.set("Comoros","Moroni");
CountryCapitalList.set("Congo","Brazzaville");
CountryCapitalList.set("Costa Rica","   San Jose");
CountryCapitalList.set("Cote d'Ivoire","Yamoussoukro");
CountryCapitalList.set("Croatia","Zagreb");
CountryCapitalList.set("Cuba","Havana");
CountryCapitalList.set("Cyprus","Nicosia");
CountryCapitalList.set("Czech Republic","Prague");
CountryCapitalList.set("Denmark","Copenhagen");
CountryCapitalList.set("Djibouti","Djibouti");
CountryCapitalList.set("Dominica","Roseau");
CountryCapitalList.set("Dominican Republic","Santo Domingo");
CountryCapitalList.set("Ecuador","Quito");
CountryCapitalList.set("Egypt","Cairo");
CountryCapitalList.set("El Salvador","San Salvador");
CountryCapitalList.set("Guinea","Malabo");
CountryCapitalList.set("Eritrea","Asmara");
CountryCapitalList.set("Estonia","Tallinn");
CountryCapitalList.set("Ethiopia","Addis Ababa");
CountryCapitalList.set("Fiji","Suva");
CountryCapitalList.set("Finland","Helsinki");
CountryCapitalList.set("France","Paris");
CountryCapitalList.set("Gabon","Libreville");
CountryCapitalList.set("Gambia","Banjul");
CountryCapitalList.set("Georgia","Tbilisi");
CountryCapitalList.set("Germany","Berlin");
CountryCapitalList.set("Ghana","Accra");
CountryCapitalList.set("Greece","Athens");
CountryCapitalList.set("Grenada","Saint George's");
CountryCapitalList.set("Guatemala","Guatemala City");
CountryCapitalList.set("Guinea","Conakry");
CountryCapitalList.set("Guinea-Bissau","Bissau");
CountryCapitalList.set("Guyana","Georgetown");
CountryCapitalList.set("Haiti","Port-au-Prince");
CountryCapitalList.set("Honduras","Tegucigalpa");
CountryCapitalList.set("Hungary","Budapest");
CountryCapitalList.set("Iceland","Reykjavik");
CountryCapitalList.set("India","New Delhi");
CountryCapitalList.set("Indonesia","Jakarta");
CountryCapitalList.set("Iran","Tehran");
CountryCapitalList.set("Iraq","Baghdad");
CountryCapitalList.set("Ireland","Dublin");
CountryCapitalList.set("Israel","Jerusalem");
CountryCapitalList.set("Italy","Rome");
CountryCapitalList.set("Jamaica","Kingston");
CountryCapitalList.set("Japan","Tokyo");
CountryCapitalList.set("Jordan","Amman");
CountryCapitalList.set("Kazakhstan","Astana");
CountryCapitalList.set("Kenya","Nairobi");
CountryCapitalList.set("Kiribati","Tarawa");
CountryCapitalList.set("Kosovo","Pristina");
CountryCapitalList.set("Kuwait","Kuwait City");
CountryCapitalList.set("Laos","Bishkek");
CountryCapitalList.set("Latvia","Riga");
CountryCapitalList.set("Lebanon","Beirut");
CountryCapitalList.set("Lesotho","Maseru");
CountryCapitalList.set("Liberia","Monrovia");
CountryCapitalList.set("Libya","Tripoli");
CountryCapitalList.set("Liechtenstein","Vaduz");
CountryCapitalList.set("Lithuania","Vilnius");
CountryCapitalList.set("Luxembourg","Luxembourg");
CountryCapitalList.set("Macedonia","Skopje");
CountryCapitalList.set("Madagascar","Antananarivo");
CountryCapitalList.set("Malawi","Lilongwe");
CountryCapitalList.set("Malaysia","Kuala Lumpur");
CountryCapitalList.set("Maldives","Male");
CountryCapitalList.set("Mali","Bamako");
CountryCapitalList.set("Malta","Valletta");
CountryCapitalList.set("Marshall Islands","Majuro");
CountryCapitalList.set("Mauritania","Nouakchott");
CountryCapitalList.set("Mauritius","Port Louis");
CountryCapitalList.set("Mexico","Mexico City");
CountryCapitalList.set("Micronesia","Palikir");
CountryCapitalList.set("Moldova","Chisinau");
CountryCapitalList.set("Monaco","Monaco");
CountryCapitalList.set("Mongolia","Ulaanbaatar");
CountryCapitalList.set("Montenegro","Podgorica");
CountryCapitalList.set("Morocco","Rabat");
CountryCapitalList.set("Mozambique","Maputo");
CountryCapitalList.set("Myanmar","Naypyidaw");
CountryCapitalList.set("Namibia","Windhoek");
CountryCapitalList.set("Nauru","Yaren District");
CountryCapitalList.set("Nepal","Kathmandu");
CountryCapitalList.set("Netherlands","Amsterdam");
CountryCapitalList.set("New Zealand","Wellington");
CountryCapitalList.set("Nigeria","Abuja");
CountryCapitalList.set("Nicaragua","Managua");
CountryCapitalList.set("Niger","Niamey");
CountryCapitalList.set("North Korea","Pyongyang");
CountryCapitalList.set("Norway","Oslo");
CountryCapitalList.set("Oman","Muscat");
CountryCapitalList.set("Pakistan","Islamabad");
CountryCapitalList.set("Palau","Ngerulmud");
CountryCapitalList.set("Palestine","Jerusalem");
CountryCapitalList.set("Panama","Panama City");
CountryCapitalList.set("New Guinea","Port Moresby");
CountryCapitalList.set("Paraguay","Asunción");
CountryCapitalList.set("Peru","Lima");
CountryCapitalList.set("Philippines","Manila");
CountryCapitalList.set("Poland","Warsaw");
CountryCapitalList.set("Portugal","Lisbon");
CountryCapitalList.set("Qatar","Doha");
CountryCapitalList.set("Romania","Bucharest");
CountryCapitalList.set("Russia","Moscow");
CountryCapitalList.set("Rwanda","Kigali");
CountryCapitalList.set("Saint Kitts and Nevis","Basseterre");
CountryCapitalList.set("Saint Lucia ","Castries");
CountryCapitalList.set("Saint Vincent and the Grenadines","Kingstown");
CountryCapitalList.set("Samoa","Apia");
CountryCapitalList.set("San Marino","San Marino");
CountryCapitalList.set("Sao Tome and Principe","Sao Tome");
CountryCapitalList.set("Saudi Arabia","Riyadh");
CountryCapitalList.set("Senegal","Dakar");
CountryCapitalList.set("Serbia","Belgrade");
CountryCapitalList.set("Seychelles","Victoria");
CountryCapitalList.set("Sierra Leone","Freetown");
CountryCapitalList.set("Singapore","Singapore");
CountryCapitalList.set("Slovakia","Bratislava");
CountryCapitalList.set("Slovenia","Ljubljana");
CountryCapitalList.set("Solomon Islands","Honiara");
CountryCapitalList.set("Somalia","Mogadishu");
CountryCapitalList.set("South Africa","Cape Town ");
CountryCapitalList.set("South Korea","Seoul");
CountryCapitalList.set("South Sudan","Juba");
CountryCapitalList.set("Spain","Madrid");
CountryCapitalList.set("Sri Lanka","Sri Jayawardenepura Kotte");
CountryCapitalList.set("Sudan","Khartoum");
CountryCapitalList.set("Suriname","Paramaribo");
CountryCapitalList.set("Swaziland","Mbabane,Lobamba");
CountryCapitalList.set("Sweden","Stockholm");
CountryCapitalList.set("Switzerland","Bern");
CountryCapitalList.set("Syria","Damascus");
CountryCapitalList.set("Taiwan","Taipei");
CountryCapitalList.set("Tajikistan","Dushanbe");
CountryCapitalList.set("Tanzania","Dodoma");
CountryCapitalList.set("Thailand","Bangkok");
CountryCapitalList.set("Timor-Leste","Dili");
CountryCapitalList.set("Togo","Lome");
CountryCapitalList.set("Tonga","Nukualofa");
CountryCapitalList.set("Tunisia","Tunis");
CountryCapitalList.set("Trinidad and Tobago","Port of Spain");
CountryCapitalList.set("Turkey","Ankara");
CountryCapitalList.set("Turkmenistan","Ashgabat");
CountryCapitalList.set("Tuvalu","Funafuti");
CountryCapitalList.set("Uganda","Kampala");
CountryCapitalList.set("Ukraine","Kiev");
CountryCapitalList.set("United Arab Emirates","Abu Dhabi");
CountryCapitalList.set("United Kingdom","London");
CountryCapitalList.set("England","London");
CountryCapitalList.set("U.S.","Washington, D.C.");
CountryCapitalList.set("US","Washington, D.C.");
CountryCapitalList.set("United States","Washington, D.C.");
CountryCapitalList.set("Uzbekistan","Tashkent");
CountryCapitalList.set("Vanuatu","Port Vila");
CountryCapitalList.set("Vatican","Vatican");
CountryCapitalList.set("Venezuela","Caracas");
CountryCapitalList.set("Vietnam","Hanoi");
CountryCapitalList.set("Yemen","Sana");
CountryCapitalList.set("Zambia","Lusaka");
CountryCapitalList.set("Zimbabwe","Harare");
CountryCapitalList.set("Zaire","Kinshasa");
CountryCapitalList.set("Cape Verde","Praya");
```

```
var ModerCap;
    var ModerText;
    var MessageCapText;
    ModerCap = $(".messages li:last-child");
    ModerText = ModerCap.children(".msg-body");
    MessageCapText = ModerText.text().toLowerCase();
    CountryCapitalList.forEach(function (value, key, map) {
        if((MessageCapText.includes("capital") && MessageCapText.includes(key.toString().toLowerCase()))
        || (MessageCapText.includes("столица") && MessageCapText.includes(key.toString().toLowerCase())
        || MessageCapText.includes("столицу") && MessageCapText.includes(key.toString().toLowerCase())))
        {
            $(".chat-input").val(value);
            console.log(value);
        }
        else if(((MessageCapText.includes("city") ||MessageCapText.includes("capital")) && MessageCapText.includes(value.toString().toLowerCase()))
        || (MessageCapText.includes("столица") && MessageCapText.includes(value.toString().toLowerCase())
        || MessageCapText.includes("столицей") &&                                 MessageCapText.includes(value.toString().toLowerCase())))
                {
                    $(".chat-input").val(key);
                    console.log("key");
                }
    })
```

Comment: Guessing it's a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) @ErikPhilips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are testing if the message text contains the `key` of your map records and one of the keys is `"US"`. So it will be found in `belarus` as the last two chars match. It might be better to split the message and check each word if it is equal to the key instead of included in the whole message.

Comment: thanks a lot,i get it. I am dumb a bit to think of that ;p